# Cash-or-nothing and Asset-or-nothing price derivation

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, derivatives, exotics

I was wondering how to derive the price of a cash-or-nothing and asset-or-nothing option by trying to work out the expectation under the risk-neutral measure, while assuming that the underlying follows a Geometric Brownian motion.

I know that the value of the Asset-or-nothing call is supposed to be $Value = S_0\Phi(d_1)$

Furthermore the value of the Cash-or-nothing call should be $Value = e^{-rT}A\Phi(d2)$, if we assume that it pays out A if $S_T > K$.

Yet I don't know how to derive these results myself, and I haven't been able to find a book that does it

Comment: Please see discussion here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15489/derivation-of-the-formulas-for-the-values-of-european-asset-or-nothing-and-cash

Comment: Yes I did see the discussion before posting, but I still don't quite understand it

Comment: Try to find the black schools derivation and then these are just the two components of BS.

Comment: And here: http://www.ltnielsen.com/wp-content/uploads/Understanding.pdf

Comment: Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900911/proof-of-the-black-scholes-pricing-formula-for-european-call-option

Comment: I now get the right solution for the cash-or-nothing call option, but not yet the asset-or-nothing, as we there have the $S_T$ in the integral instead of the constant A.

Comment: Let me know if you get stuck!